# How to prevent auto-closing of curly braces in ReSharper?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, resharper

A simple question.

I'm trying out ReSharper and it closes my curly braces for me as soon as I open them. I really dislike this "feature" and I've had about three long looks through the settings window and I can't seem to figure out how to disable it! Am I missing an obvious check-box somewhere?

**Edit:**

The unchecking of "Auto close parenthesis after completion" does *not* do the trick!

I want to be able to type the following without `}` appearing for me:

```
if(true){
```

This doesn't seem like anything to do with intellisense completion.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

To turn off this behaviour, open the ReSharper options and on the **Editor** tab, untick the **Auto-insert closing brace** option. There should be no need to restart Visual Studio.

Comment: Superb!!! I'm not sure how I missed that, it pretty much spells it out for you. They could do with a "search" tool for their options... anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: +1 don't know how i missed that one either.  removed my erroneous answer.

Comment: Awesome.  Because in ASPX pages this is PARTICULARLY frustrating and buggy.

Comment: @Vibo: Do you have another plugin installed that inserts braces? (see Lee's answer)

Comment: Make sure that you also disable a similar functionality in Visual Studio. For example in C#, un-tick *Automatic brace completion* in Options - Text Editor - C# -  General.

Answer (score 11):

FYI:  I thought there was a bug in ReSharper until I realised Microsoft's "Productivity Power Tools" plugin also has an automatic brace completion option which is set to on by default.

To turn it off: Tools > Productivity Power Tools > Automatic Brace Completion > Off

Answer (score 10):

Go to `ReSharper Options->Environment->Editor->Edit Behavior` and disable "Auto-insert closing brace". Additionally, if this is a new Visual Studio install, newer versions also do this by default. You'll have to go to `Options->Text Editor->C#->General` and disable "Automatic brace completion".