# How can I stop Visual Studio 2010 from inserting } when I type { in C#?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

When I type

```
new List<T> {
```

How can I stop Visual Studio from automatically changing it to

```
new List<T> {}
```

Comment: Why would you want to? After all, the `}` is syntactically needed.

Comment: because I want to manually insert it myself

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587470/how-to-prevent-auto-closing-of-curly-braces-in-resharper

Comment: I had this problem too..I usually add the closing bracket myself and I ended up with 2 closing brackets:)

Comment: @radashk your link relates to Resharper? which i'm not currently using, however I do think this is the "Productivity Power tools" doing this so I will check there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tools > Productivity Power Tools > Automatic Brace Completion > Off

That sorts it :)

I didn't realise it was that plugin until now.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Visual Studio by default does not inserts `}`. It's can be done by ReSharper or other plugins such as Productivity Power Tools.

Comment: Yea just noticed that its the "Productivity power tools"